# C# datetimepicker clear specific items

Tags: c#, java, datetime, calendar, datetimepicker

I have a Java application I'm trying to convert to C#. I have solved a fair bit of the program, but I have this clear method that troubles me:

```
private void checkCourts()
{
    if (splMonth.getSelectedValue() != null && splDate.getSelectedValue() != null)
    {
        courtModel.clear();
        Calendar booking = new GregorianCalendar();

        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = new Scanner(splMonth.getSelectedValue().toString()).nextInt() - 1;
        int date = new Scanner(splDate.getSelectedValue().toString()).nextInt();
        int time = Integer.parseInt(cmbxTime.getSelectedItem().toString());
        int currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        booking.set(year, month, date, time, 0, 0);

        if (month > currentMonth || (month == currentMonth && date > currentDate) || (month == currentMonth && date == currentDate && time > currentTime))
        {

            try
            {
                ArrayList<Reservation> rs = BookingManager.getInstance().getReservations();
                Reservation r = new Reservation(booking);
                ArrayList<String> courtNames = BookingManager.getInstance().getCourtsName();

                for (int i = 0; i < rs.size(); i++)
                {

                    r.getReservationTime().clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                    rs.get(i).getReservationTime().clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
                }

                if (!rs.contains(r))
                {
                    for (String c : courtNames)
                    {
                        courtModel.addElement(c);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (String c : courtNames)
                    {
                        courtModel.addElement(c);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < rs.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (r.getReservationTime().getTime().equals(rs.get(i).getReservationTime().getTime()))
                        {
                            String courtName = BookingManager.getInstance().getNameById(rs.get(i).getCourtId());
                            courtModel.removeElement(courtName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                splCourt.setModel(courtModel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR - " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Den valgte dato er ikke tilgængelig for booking.", "Advarsel", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the top for loop is the real issue, I think. I would like to remove the reservation times that already have been booked.

This is my first for loop try-out:

```
private void checkCourts()
    {
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;

        int year = Int32.Parse(DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy"));
        int currentYear = current.Year;

        int month = Int32.Parse(DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("MM"));
        int currentMonth = current.Month;

        int day = Int32.Parse(DateTimePicker.Value.ToString("dd"));
        int currentDay = current.Day;

        int time = (int)cmbxTime.SelectedItem;

        int currentTime = current.TimeOfDay.Hours;

        string date1 = year.ToString() + "," + month.ToString() + "," + day.ToString();
        DateTime thisdate = DateTime.Parse(date1);
        thisdate = thisdate.AddHours(time);

        List<Reservation> rs = BookingManager.getInstance().getReservations();
        Reservation r = new Reservation(thisdate);
        List<string> courtNames = BookingManager.getInstance().getCourtsName();

        if (month > currentMonth || (month == currentMonth && day > currentDay) ||
            (month == currentMonth && day == currentDay && time > currentTime) && year >= currentYear)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rs.Count; i++)
                {
                    r.ReservationTime = r.ReservationTime.AddTicks(-r.ReservationTime.Ticks % 10000000);
                    rs[i].ReservationTime = rs[i].ReservationTime.AddTicks(-rs[i].ReservationTime.Ticks % 10000000);
                }

                if (!rs.Contains(r))
                {
                    foreach (string c in courtNames)
                    {
                        lboxCourts.Items.Add(c);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (string c in courtNames)
                    {
                        lboxCourts.Items.Add(c);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < rs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (r.ReservationTime.Equals(rs[i].ReservationTime))
                        {
                            String courtName = BookingManager.getInstance().getNameById(rs[i].CourtId);
                            lboxCourts.Items.Remove(courtName);
                            MessageBox.Show("is equal");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Den valgte dato er ikke gyldig! - vær opmærksom på at hvis du vælger dags dato, at tidspunktet ikke kan være tidligere end nuværende tidspunkt!");
        }
    }
```

Hope you can clear my sight.. I have simply lost focus. I know of what I have see online - that datetimepicker is not that easy to edit. But then I would just edit the already booked item - to something like "already booked".

Comment: Try:  `DateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;` along with  `DateDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28int%29), your Java code `.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND)` is simply removing any milliseconds from the value.  It's not doing anything with your application logic to remove the actual reservation times.  It doesn't appear to involve any kind of `DateTimePicker` either.

Assuming in c# that the `ReservationTime` is a `DateTime` property, and `r.ReservationTime` is a different property than `rs[i].ReservationTime`, then you would need to do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rs.Count; i++)
{
   r.ReservationTime = r.ReservationTime.AddTicks(-r.ReservationTime.Ticks % 10000000);
   rs[i].ReservationTime = rs[i].ReservationTime.AddTicks(-rs[i].ReservationTime.Ticks % 10000000);
}
```

There are a couple of points to note:

- Java's `Calendar` class has resolution to the millisecond, so removing milliseconds would be truncating the value to the second.
- `DateTime` in .Net has resolution to the *tick*.  I tick is 100 nanoseconds, so there are 10,000,000 ticks in a second.
- Therefore, you can't just clear the milliseconds, you have to clear by computing the remainder of ticks smaller than one second.  Those are then subtracted from the original value, getting you the same result.
- `DateTime` in .Net is immutable, so you can't just change one property.  You have to compute a new value, and then assign it back to the original variable.

Comment: Hello...

I have now added all my code from the method.
I have this listbox in c# - using a jscrollpane in java - and using a defaultlistmodel.

How can i make my c# program act like my java.. only showing the available bookings.

Comment: Ohhh... now.. 
This loop you had a go on.. the reason why it cleans out the milli is to see if the hours is equal.

The two lines in my for loop checks if the chosen reservation (with hours) is in any reservations in the database..
I'm trying to solve this - I'll give you a heads-up if i can fix this on my own.. but thanks for the "solution" - i'll give you rep if it works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rs.Count; i++)
                {
                    r.ReservationTime = r.ReservationTime;
                    rs[i].ReservationTime = DateTime.Parse(rs[i].ReservationTime.ToString());

                    if (thisdate.CompareTo(rs[i].ReservationTime) != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string c in courtNames)
                        {
                            lboxCourts.Items.Add(c);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lboxCourts.Items.Clear();
                        foreach (string c in courtNames)
                        {
                            lboxCourts.Items.Add(c);
                        }

                        for (int j = 0; j < rs.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (r.ReservationTime.Equals(rs[j].ReservationTime))
                            {
                                string courtName = BookingManager.getInstance().getNameById(rs[j].CourtId);
                                lboxCourts.Items.Remove(courtName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Den valgte dato er ikke gyldig! - vær opmærksom på at hvis du vælger dags dato, at tidspunktet ikke kan være tidligere end nuværende tidspunkt!");
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help... now my method is removing the already booked courts ;-)

Kindest regards
Rasmus